# What is needed to implement a program like JConsole

Tags: java, jvm, jconsole

I need hints to implement a program that can monitor java applications like JConsole.
Where to start and what books to read. I was guided to read a book named "Inside the java virtual machine". But after skimming the chapters I don't think it's enough.

Comment: jconsole is basically a generic jmx client.

Answer (score 3):

There is a big part of JDK called [Serviceability](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/) that provides a powerful set of instruments for making various debugging and monitoring tools.

Serviceability components include both public APIs:

- [JMX (Java Management Extensions)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html)
- [JVM Tool Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html)
- [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)

and private OpenJDK-specific components:

- [Jvmstat Performance Counters](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bjvmstat)
- [Dynamic Attach mechanism](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#battach)
- [HotSpot Serviceability Agent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bsa)

These are intensively used in JDK internal tools including `jstack`, `jmap`, `jstat`, `jvisualvm`, `jconsole` etc. Public API is documented better, private is worse, but you can always consult [OpenJDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a006fa0a9e8f/src/share/classes/sun/tools/) for these tools to find how they are implemented.